# Ansible: read yaml file from remote location into variable

Tags: ansible

I want to read a yaml file on the remote location with Ansible and store the content to a variable which can be used my playbook during its runtime. Is this possible?

Comment: Search for the `slurp` module and the `b64decode` filter.

Comment: Sounds very good, but how can you bring the yaml it into a variable?

Comment: @Andreas Yes you can: `include_vars` module.

Comment: Thank you @lainatnavi. Can you please give me an example using `slurp` in combination with `include_vars`, because I cannot find this combination in Ansible documentation or using Google?

Comment: @Andreas chech this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35410248/ansible-include-vars-file-from-remote-host

Comment: @Andreas, when you say remote location, you mean git location or for instance using a yaml in consul? Could you please specify how do you want to read your file?

Comment: Use `slurp` with register then `b64decode` the slurp result directly in a variable with `set_fact`. That's one way of doing it.

Answer (score 4):

Run a command to output the content of the file (e.g. `curl` if you are fetching over http or `cat` if the file is on a local filesystem), then feed it to [`from_yaml`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#formatting-data-yaml-and-json):

```
- name: "Read yaml file"
  ansible.builtin.shell: "cat /path/to/file.yaml"
  register: result
  
- name: "Parse yaml into variable"
  set_fact:
    my_yaml: "{{ result.stdout | from_yaml }}"
```

You can then access the yaml via the `my_yaml` variable.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [ansible.builtin.slurp](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/slurp_module.html) module to read the content of the remote file and then interpret the content as yaml:

```yaml
- name: Get content of remote file
  ansible.builtin.slurp:
    src: /path/to/remote/file.yml
  register: remote_file

- name: Interpret remote file content as yaml
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    remote_yaml: '{{ remote_file.content | b64decode | from_yaml }}'

- name: Print yaml for debugging purposes
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    var: remote_yaml
```